# Elastic Search bulk need to add headers

Tags: perl, elasticsearch

Do we have the option to add header in the Search::Elasticsearch module.

```
    use Search::Elasticsearch; 

     my $esloc='abc.com';

     my $es = Search::Elasticsearch->new(nodes => [
            "$esloc"],
            timeout => 60,
            no_refresh   => 0,
            userinfo => 'username:password'
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
 my $es = Search::Elasticsearch->new(nodes => [
        "$esloc"],
        timeout => 60,
        no_refresh   => 0,
        userinfo => 'username:password',
        default_headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/ndjson' }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks @Val. I have tried to add my custom header. It's not accepting it. Do we need to add anything for that... ?

Comment: Thanks for your Swift Response